# Reading and writing multiple structs into a file

Tags: c++

I'm trying to store multiple structs into an file and my problem is that when I try to add 2 structs into the same file, my second struct overwrites my first struct and when I go print out my first struct, its print out my second struct. I want to have multiple structs in my file that I can display one at a time and edit them one at a time if I want. Any clue on what's wrong with my code?

```
int main()
{
Record record1;
Record record2;
int choice;
int choice2;

cout << "Welcome to your Records! What do you want to do today?" << endl;
cout << endl << endl;



while(choice2 != -1)
{
    cout << " " << endl;
    cout << "1) Add new records to the file" << endl;
    cout << "2) Display any record in the file" << endl;
    cout << "3) Change any record in the file" << endl;
    cout << "4) Exit" << endl;
    cout << "Your Choice: ";
    cin >> choice;

    while(choice < 1 || choice > 4)
    {
        cout << "Invalid choice! Enter again" << endl;
        cin >> choice;
    }

    if(choice == 1)
    {
        ofstream outFile("RecordFile.dat", ios::out | ios::binary);
        AddItem(outFile);
        outFile.close();

    }
    else if(choice == 2)
    {
        ifstream inFile("RecordFile.dat",ios::out | ios::binary);
        DisplayItem(inFile);
        inFile.close();

    }
    else if(choice == 3)
    {
        ofstream outFile("RecordFile.dat", ios::out | ios::binary);
        EditItem(outFile);
        outFile.close();
    }

    else if(choice == 4)
    {
        choice2 = -1;
    }

}

return 0;
}
```

Header File

```
struct Record
{
char  name[15];
int quantity;
double wholesalecost;
double retailcost;
};

void AddItem(ofstream& outFile);
void DisplayItem(ifstream& inFile);
void EditItem(ofstream& outFile);
```

Functions

```
void AddItem(ofstream& outFile)
{
  Record record;

  cout << "What is the name of this record: ";
  cin.ignore();
  cin.getline(record.name,15);
  cout << "How many do we have(quantity): ";
  cin >> record.quantity;
  cout << "Whats the whole sale cost: ";
  cin >> record.wholesalecost;
  cout << "Whats the retail cost of " << record.name << ":";
  cin >> record.retailcost;

if(outFile)
{
    outFile.write((char*)&(record),sizeof(record));

}
else
{
    cout << "File not Found" << endl;
}
}

void DisplayItem(ifstream& inFile)
{
  Record record;
  int recordnum;
  cout << "Enter what record number you want to display " << endl;
  cin >> recordnum;
  recordnum--;

if(inFile)
{
    inFile.seekg(sizeof(Record) * recordnum, ios::beg);
    inFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&record), sizeof(record));

    cout << "Name: " << record.name << endl;
    cout << "Quantity: " << record.quantity << endl;
    cout << "Whole Sale Cost: " << record.wholesalecost << endl;
    cout << "Retail Cost: " << record.retailcost << endl;
}
else
{
    cout << "File not found" << endl;
}
}
```

Comment: Probably unrelated: the `cin.ignore();` at the beginning of `AddItem` will bring you nothing but pain. It's better to ignore AFTER a read leaves something in the stream that you want removed rather than before reading an unrelated input. If you ignore before reading, just in case, you almost always find a case where you throw out data you need because there was nothing in the stream that needed ignoring.

Comment: ok thanks for the info, i didnt know that

Answer (score 0):

You are writing everything to the beginning of the file, so of course multiple writes overwrite eachother.

You need to define a file format that can contain multiple records and a way to find where to write new records that doesn't overlap with previous ones, as well as an easy way to find the location of existing records.

Have you considered just using a SQL (or other type of) database?

Comment: `ios::app` may be helpful here. Sidenote: you don't have to specify `ios::out` for an `ofstream`. It's implied. Same for `ios::in` and `ifstream`s.

Comment: @user4581301 Just naively appending to the file will only work well if all records are the exact same size or there's some identifiable delimiter. Most file formats will have a header block at the start telling you where different records start/end (or similar). I'd say; just use a database already - sqlite works nicely ;)

Comment: @user4581301 You may (sadly) be right. But I'm not going to let that stop me from proposing a *proper* solution.